# FFmpeg Drawbox Errors?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg version 4.3.2.

Command:

```
ffmpeg -y

  -i /usr/src/app/backgrounds/pink-blue.jpg
  -i files/fuzzy-octopus-5/path/file.webm
  -i files/fuzzy-octopus-5/path/file.webm
  -i /usr/src/app/logo.png
  -filter_complex "
    [0]drawbox=x=-140:y=(((H-th)/2) - 205):w=840:h=490:color=white@0.2:t=fill,
       drawbox=x=770:y=(((H-th)/2) - 205):w=840:h=490:color=white@0.2:t=fill[bg]; 
    ...
```

However I am getting the following errors?

```
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #3:0
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error reinitializing filters!
[Parsed_drawbox_0 @ 0x564a87058e80] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_drawbox_0
[Parsed_drawbox_0 @ 0x564a87058e80] Error when evaluating the expression '(((H-th)/2) - 205)'.
Last message repeated 5 times
[Parsed_drawbox_0 @ 0x564a87058e80] [Eval @ 0x7ffcf25dc650] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'H-th)/2)-205)'
```

I have the right amount of brackets and this definitely works on my local machine (macOS). It's only throwing this error in our deployed AWS EC2 linux instance.

Any ideas? Thanks!

*Update: Tried replacing `th` with `h` but get the same error*

Comment: *this definitely works on my local machine (macOS)* --> unlikely. The drawbox filter has no variable called `th`

Comment: I tried replacing th with h and get the same error: `[Parsed_drawbox_0 @ 0x55cabe3409c0] Error when evaluating the expression '(((H-h)/2) - 205)'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using arbitrary, unsupported variables. Refer to the [drawbox documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox) for a list of supported variables (under the section "*The parameters for x, y, w and h and t are expressions containing the following constants*").

I can only guess what you are trying to do, but here is a simplified valid example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]drawbox=x=-140:y=(((ih-h)/2) - 205):w=840:h=490:color=white@0.2:t=fill" output.mp4
```